# Scroll to Top inside the browser using Java Applet

Tags: java, browser, applet

I can not figure this one out.  Is there anyway Java Applet can scroll the webpage that it's displayed to Top?

I am Not talking about the scroll bar inside the Java Applet, I'm talking about browser's scroll bar.

let's say I have very tall applet.  so browser has a scrollbar on the side to scroll down to bottom of the applet.

in the bottom, there's a button to click "Back To Top".

How do I make that button work?  Mind you that there is No scrollbar within the applet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to call javascript code from within your applet. Thus create a jscript method which scrolls to the top and call it from your java code.

More infos [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will certainly try that.  That is probably the easiest and cleanest way to do it.  Invoke JavaScript from Applet